# Add orderby="rand" function in wpbakery Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, visual-composer, wpbakery

I have a theme for an eCommerce website and my homepage is built with wpbakery. Products displayed in the homepage are not changing after refresh. All the products are in the same place. I found no option in wpbakery elements to change order by random. How can I add this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure in wpbakery there is a way you can do this by selecting a random option. But if you are unable to find it check and see if this works in your case.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
    }
}
```

Put the code in your function file. It will set your homepage post orderby rand. Hope it works but I advise you to follow WPbakery setting to do that.

Simple Steps to find your way in WPbakery

1. make sure your plugin is active
2. Go to the page set as your homepage and click on edit page
3. open the post setting in the wpbakery
4. Select Data setting
5. Choose the first option which is "Order by"
6. scroll down and select "Random order" and save your setting.
   That should point you to the right way to set random post order in WPbakery.

Comment: No option for data setting

Comment: It means to help you further you may need someone that will check your site directly for you. The above code and the steps I mentioned above are very correct and I am very sure wpbakery has an option for that as I mentioned. I used wpbakery in the past and know the plugin perfectly well. someone may need a closer look to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you check it out for me?

Comment: Ok let's see how it goes.